# Cloud-init: how to install it from the source code?

Tags: 16.04, cloud-init

I have a `Ubuntu 1604` VM on `Azure`, which by default has `cloud-init` installed.

To debug a `cloud-init` issue, I removed the default `cloud-init` (`apt remove cloud-init`) and cloned the source code from `https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/` and want to build my version of `cloud-init` to debug.

Could you please help me:

1. How to compile cloud-init from the source code tree?
2. How to install cloud-init from my local source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to use Ubuntu specific source which contains necessary patches, bug fixes, etc.

To download the source:

```
apt source --download-only cloud-init
```

To download, extract, apply Ubuntu/Debian patches to fix bugs, security issues:

```
apt source --download cloud-init
```

To compile, first install packages that are necessary for build process:

```
apt build-dep cloud-init
```

then use:

```
apt source --compile cloud-init
```

---

If you want to change the source, first download and extract it, then install built dependencies and after you have made your changes build it:

```
apt source --download cloud-init
apt build-dep cloud-init
# Add your changes
apt source --compile cloud-init
```

---

After compile process is done, you have a `.deb` file, install it using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a more complete answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845732/117471

The basic answer is:

```
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install --init-system systemd
sudo cloud-init init --local
```

Credit: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27U_6.4.0/com.ibm.zvm.v640.hcpo5/instsubuntu.htm